# PDFBox is extracting text out of order

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a PDF file which I have to extract text and get some info.
The file is like this:

[image]

I am extracting the text this way:

```
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
            PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            String[] auxTxt = textStripper.getText(document).split("\\r?\\n");
```

When I print the text, it´s out of order. I need it to be column like, or line like...

Example:

(Line 1) `Fonte Restrição Energia Vertida Turbinável Valor de restrição e variação em relação ao mês anterior`

(Line 2) `Energética Com EVT 22.660MWh`

(Line 3) `(-70%)`

(Line 4) `Sem EVT 466.961MWh`

...

OR:

Column 1:  `Fonte Usinas Hidráulicas`

Column 2:  `Restrição Energética Elétrica (indisponibilidade Externa) Confiabilidade Elétrica`

...

The text should be extracted any way, it´s just has to be in order.
BUT.... when I print the extracted text: this is what I got.

```
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)  Usinas Hidráulicas
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Usinas 
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Hidráulicas
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Energética
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Confiabilidade
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Elétrica
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Elétrica 
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) (indisponibilidade
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Externa)
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Com EVT
10:26:48,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Sem EVT
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Com EVT
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Sem EVT
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Com EVT
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Sem EVT
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Fonte Restrição
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Energia Vertida 
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Turbinável
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Valor de restrição e variação 
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) em relação ao mês anterior
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 466.961 MWh
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) (10%)
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 22.660 MWh
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) (-70%)
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 607 MWh
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) (-81%)
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 90 MWh
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) (-96%)
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Não houve 
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) restrição
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Não houve 
10:26:48,934 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) restrição
```

So that´s it. How can I extract the text on the PDF in the proper order? (Lines or Columns)

Thanks!

Comment: If you use `textStripper.setSortByPosition(true)`, the result may be a bit nearer to what you get without. If the text of interest always is at the same position, you may also try the `PDFTextStripperByArea` for the rectangles of interest.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it and reach back to you!

Comment: Hey man. That did exactcly what I wanted, so, if you want, post this as an answer so I can accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main options:

- If you use `textStripper.setSortByPosition(true)`, the text pieces gets sorted by their position on the page.
- If the text of interest always is at the same position, you may also try the `PDFTextStripperByArea` for the rectangles of interest